# Print something using Static Block

Tags: java, static

I tried to print something using static block without Main method.
But how do I know at the time of the class loading static block will be
called.

Here removing main method its not printing anything in CMD as well as in Eclipse IDE.

> Output :(with main method)

Static Block Called........
i :6

```
public class StaticBlock
{
  static int i = 5;
  static 
  {
      System.out.println("Static Block Called........");
    i ++;  
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      System.out.println("i :"+i);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you remove the main method then it should print Static Block called and give exception main not found

Comment: How are you running the **class** without `main` method ?

Comment: I assume you delete your `main` from the StaticBlock class but you are placing it in some other class that you are executing otherwise you are not execute anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your StaticBlock class will not be loaded unless it is not referred form somewhere. Having the main method causes your class to be loaded  because jvm loads the class when you run it. As soon as you refer your StaticBlock class, anywhere in your project, be it the main method in the same class or the main method in a different class. That will cause the class to be loaded and as soon as class will be laoded, static block in that class will be executed.

By refer I mean either you create an instance of it or you use any public method or field of the class using hte class name i.e StaticBlock.filed or StaticBlock.method().

In short, a class static block is executed when the class gets loaded by a classloader.

Comment: What do you mean by 'refer your StaticBlock class' ? Because just a reference to the class won't load the class. The constructor of the class, or any static method of the class has to be called to load the class.

Comment: And if a class is requested to be run, but it lacks a main method? Will it not be loaded first?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why wouldn't it be? I mentioned "Your StaticBlock class will not be loaded unless it is not referred form somewhere". And By refer I mean either you create an instance of it or you use any public method or field of the class using hte class name i.e StaticBlock.filed or StaticBlock.method().

Comment: So it will be loaded even if there's no main method? And then the static block will run anyway, isn't that correct?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It has to be referred to be loaded. Having a main method causes it to be loaded because we tell the jvm to run this class. When jvm has to run the class it will be loaded.

Comment: So *not having a main method* will not cause it to be loaded? How can the JVM even know that there's no main method without loading the class?

Comment: In the context of the class given in the question, and if that is the only class in the project. First of all, you cannot run this class if it does not have main. I have tried to tell that, when static block will be executed depending if you have a main in the current class or in some other class.

Comment: But you can cause the class to be *loaded* whether or not it has `main`, just by passing its name to the `java` command.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a behavioral detail which has changed in Java 7.

Prior to Java 7, whatever class is passed to the JVM as the application entry point, that class is loaded, *initialized*, and then the `main` method is looked up. Even if there's no such method, the class initialization code will have run. That includes any static initializers.

As of Java 7, the class will be loaded, but will *not be initialized* prior to looking up the `main` method. The JVM will abort with an error if the method is not found, and initialization will never occur.

### Class loading vs. initialization

For many purposes this is just a subtle difference, but you have actually hit one where it is crucial. As per Java Language / Java Virtual Machine specifications, there is a clear distinction between:

1. class *loading*: this happens at any time, and for any class, the specific JVM implementation sees fit. It means loading the binary contents of the .class file, parsing them, verifying the bytecode, building up the constant pool, and so on;
2. class *initialization*: this happens at a precisely specified point, which is when the class is referred to (explicitly or otherwise) for the first time during a JVM run. At this point all the class initializers run.

Comment: can you please provide link to `main` method lookup in Java 7

Comment: @AlpeshGediya Tried to find a decent one, but the best I got was a discussion on CodeRanch. Sorry.